# Bound property in WPF doesn't update

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, textblock

I have a `TextBlock` in my WPF/MVVM (with MVVM Light framework) game that is bound to a property that is supposed to reflect the number of employed workers. I have confirmed that the binding is intact, but I can't get it to update.

Here's the `TextBlock` in my view:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="WorkersTextBlock"
           FontFamily="Pericles"
           DataContext="{Binding Guilds[0]}"
           Text="{Binding Workers.Count,
                          StringFormat=Workers : {0},
                          FallbackValue=Workers : 99}" />
```

The property in my viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Guild> Guilds
{
    get { return DataManager.Data.Guilds; }
}
```

Also in my viewmodel, the command to change a `Worker`'s Employer property:

```
private void ExecuteHireWorkerCommand()
{
    if (SelectedWorker == null)
        return;

    SelectedWorker.Employer = DataManager.Data.Guilds[0];
    Gold -= SelectedWorker.Salary;
    _workerCollectionView.Refresh();
}
```

In DataManager, which is a singleton class that holds all of my data:

```
private ObservableCollection<Guild> _guilds = new ObservableCollection<Guild>();
public ObservableCollection<Guild> Guilds
{
    get { return _guilds; }
}

private ObservableCollection<Worker> _workers = new ObservableCollection<Worker>();
public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers
{
    get { return _workers; }
}
```

In the `Guild` model:

```
public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers
{
    get { return DataManager.Data.Workers.Where(w => w.Employer == this).ToObservableCollection(); }
}
```

The Employer property in `Worker` is:

```
public Guild Employer { get; set; }
```

And last, my extension method (which I believe is the source of the problem):

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    return new ObservableCollection<T>(source);
}
```

Messageboxes confirm that via the command, `Worker`s' Employer properties are being updated properly but nothing I've tried makes the `TextBlock` update. I've tried implementing `RaisePropertyChanged` on everything I've listed here with no luck.

If I set the Employment property of a `Worker` to the correct guild within the constructor when the data is initialized, the number in the `TextBlock` displays correctly, but doesn't update after that. My hunch is that the LINQ filtering and extension methods in the `Workers` property are causing this trouble, but I could be wrong.

If anybody has any ideas on how to get this to work, I'd love to hear them. Any advice at all on this matter would be greatly appreciated. If you need more code or information, please ask.

Thanks.

**Update:** I think that Ron is on the right path; the extension method may be breaking the binding. If this is the case, can anybody give me any advice on how to filter the Workers property in `Guild` without breaking the binding? Also, as far as the setter issue goes, I added a setter to the Workers property but it never actually fires.

Comment: The magic might be in "I've tried implementing RaisePropertyChanged on everything I've listed here with no luck" show us that code. My guess is that you made some errors there.

Comment: I use this for notifying: http://kindofmagic.codeplex.com/ It's pretty hard to mess up and it works perfectly for other properties.

Comment: I have hardly ever seen a worse named attribute. It should be called NotifiesWhenPropertyChangesAttribute. Magic can be anything.

Comment: I changed it to [Notify]. The default name is terrible, I agree.

Comment: So you change the SelectedWorker.Employer.  But then you set SelectedWorker to null.

Comment: SelectedWorker represents the selected item in my DataGrid, bound OneWayToSource. A lot of this is new terrain for me, but actually having that line or not doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: Then where do you actually change SelectedWorker.Employer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to redesign the underlying data structure a bit.  But be that as it may, you could change it slightly to make it work.

Change the `Workers` property to `ICollectionView` like so:

`public ICollectionView Workers { get; set; }`

Then in the Guild model's contstructor you can populate the workers collection from your data manager like so:

`Workers = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DataManager.Data.Workers);`

and add a filter to your `ICollectionView` like so:

`Workers.Filter = (worker) =>
        {
          return (worker.Employer == this);
        };`

and call `Workers.Refresh()` whenever the `Workers` collection is updated.

That way your binding won't break and your `Workers` collection will retain the same instance.

Oh, and add the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your `TextBox` binding.

Like I said, I would look at redesigning the backing data structure entirely, but without knowing why or how you implemented it I cannot say more than that.

Comment: I just tried this method and got it working and it should do just fine. Thanks for your help. As far as the backing data goes, it's all stored in a singleton class for global access. This is the first real project I've taken on and I am quite inexperienced, so I really don't know of a better way to go about it. All it contains at the moment is 4 `ObservableCollection`s, one master list for each major type I'm dealing with. If you could suggest a better way to go about it, I'd love to learn it. I know what I'm doing isn't exactly ideal.

Comment: It's difficult to give you advise on how to improve the structure for the backing data if I don't have all the requirements, but I would just keep a private static `ObservableCollection` for each of your types on the `Model` itself. That way you don't have to redirect back to a data manager and everything is contained in one class. So `Guild` would be the `Model` and expose the static field/property `ObservableCollection<Guild> Guilds`. ANyway, that is one way I would do it.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the concept of models in MVVM, but right now I have a model for each of the 4 major types. Each model just contains the required public properties and a method to initialize the data. There are multiple instances of each type, so I use the singleton class to keep them all in a central location, hence the `ObservableCollection<Type>`s. I'm not sure how containing the `ObservableCollection` in the model itself would work or how it would be more efficient.

Comment: I don't know if you'd be interested in taking a look at the code, but if you are, I've posted it here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28728/efficient-strucure-for-backing-data-in-mvvm

Comment: I have looked at your code from the link you provided and drew up a quick UML diagram to illustrate how I would go about setting up the structure (with binding and scalability in mind). I will try and find time to get some code to go with what I have in mind. I will post it on that link when I get the time.

Comment: Thanks! I look forward to seeing it.

Comment: Please let me know if you can find the time to post the UML. I would still like to see it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers
{
    get { return DataManager.Data.Workers.Where(w => w.Employer == this).ToObservableCollection(); }
}
```

You're not notifying the binding system when this property actually changes. if the underlying collection itself changed, you'd be fine. But you're not even keeping a reference to that underlying collection - you're just returning it.

The normal pattern would be something like (assuming you're implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `Guild`)

```
private ObservableCollection<Worker> _Workers;
public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers
{
    get { return _Workers; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _Workers)
        {
            _Workers = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Workers")
        }
    }
}
```

But it somewhat depends on how you have your objects set up. Regardless, you need to notify the system that the collection is changing somehow.

Edit: You mention in the comments that you use Kind of Magic. I went and read the documentation. under how it works, it says

> 5) Transforms all available setters of public properties with MagicAttribute explicitly or implicitly applied.

You don't have a setter on that property, so it is not going to fix it up.

Comment: Adding a setter to the `Workers` property and adding the Notify attribute in `DataManager` doesn't change anything. And as far as the `Workers` property goes, I can't use LINQ filtering in a setter. I've managed to get around this when binding to a `DataGrid` by using a CollectionView, but I don't know what to do in this situation.

Comment: I added a placeholder setter to the Workers property in `Guild`, but it never fires even though the setter in `Worker`'s Employer property does.

Comment: I think the bottom line here is that you're not going to be able to do the binding if you're relying on LINQ filtering to make your properties. If I were you, I'd look at setting up a ViewModel that exposes the parts of your Model (Guilds, Workers for the selected Guild, etc) to the View. It takes a little bit of setup, but it'll ease your binding woes a ton.

Comment: That looks like I'm going to have to take a different route. When I remove the LINQ filtering from the property it updates without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code, but in the `Guild` Model, returning a `new ObservableCollection` (can be seen in your extension method) might **break your binding**, I suggest a little redesign in order for the binded view to be always associated with the original instance of the `ObservableCollection`.

Although I'm not using your framework, when I implement the MVVM pattern, I always make sure my ViewModel's observables remain the same instance, and I use the `Clear` method in order to replace their content in my `OnModelChanged` method, that way you don't have to handle notifications needed to alert the view of such changes and it is handled by your `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: That would certainly be ideal. LINQ filtering returns an IEnumerable, so that's where the extension method comes in. But I believe that you are correct and returning a new object is what's screwing things up here. Do you know how I might be able to use a filter of some sort in the property without breaking the binding?

Comment: I suggest you separate those 2 observable collections: Have a collection that always holds the relevant workers (populate it yourself when needed -> OnModelChanged), to which your view will bind to. this collection will only be instantiated once (and if you are not binding to the 'old' collection, might as well make it a regular List)